# Print a for loop on one line Python 3.2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print a line of code but there's a lot of it and I think it would look neater if I printed it all on one line.
I am trying to print a list with a for loop and I would like to print it all on the same line.

```
    for i in ALLROOMS:
            print(i.name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `end=" "`:

`print (i.name, end=" ")`

example:

```
In [2]: for i in range(5):
   ...:     print(i, end=" ")
   ...:     
0 1 2 3 4
```

help on `print()`:

```
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

Comment: @aging_gorrila Are you sure you're using Python 3 only?

Comment: thanks for clearing this up. Yes, I am using 2.7.6. I removed my comment. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

do you mean:

```
print "|".join(str(v) for v in L)  # => 1|2|3
#still can add condition
print "|".join(str(v) for v in L if v>0) # =>1|2|3
```

of course, you can replace "|" to any character you like.

if all items in the list are string, you can just

```
print "".join(L)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider the [pprint module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(i.name)
```

It won't necessarily print on the same line, but it's customisable as to width and such - and is generally a nice way of producing "more readable" outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
print(*tuple(i.name for i in ALLROOMS))
```